# Input/Output error while installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Hi there I was trying to restore my **Dell Inspiron 3543** to factory state after accidentally loosing my data using Dell's factory image that I backed up when I first bought the laptop.

I am facing **Input/Output error** which says there is a problem with installation media.

Stuff I tried :
1) Created alternative bootable media 
2) Tried creating live CD 
3) http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1910258

Please help me fixing.

Comment: can you be specific with your list "Created alternative bootable media" - what exact bootable media did you create? Secondly, did you verify the Ubuntu ISO's MD5 with the one published by Canonical?

Comment: by alternative bootable media I am pointing to Pendrives.
I am using the ISO image that I backed up when I bought the laptop